# Symfony set value checked on a form type choice

Tags: forms, symfony

I create a form with FormBuilder with Symfony like :

```
$builder
            ->add('timeBarOpen', 'time', array('label' => 'Ouverture Bar', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
            ->add('timeBarClose', 'time', array('label' => 'Fermeture Bar', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
            ->add('timeStartHappyHour', 'time', array('label' => 'Début Happy Hour *', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
            ->add('timeEndHappyHour', 'time', array('label' => 'Fin Happy Hour *', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
            ->add('day', 'choice', [
                'choices' => $days,
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'label' => 'Jour(s) *',
            ])
        ;
```

$days is an array :

```
$days = array(
            'Monday'    => 'Lundi',
            'Tuesday'   => 'Mardi',
            'Wednesday' => 'Mercredi',
            'Thursday'  => 'Jeudi',
            'Friday'    => 'Vendredi',
            'Saturday'  => 'Samedi',
            'Sunday'    => 'Dimanche',
        );
```

So, this field type "choice" generates multiple checkboxes and I need them *all* to be checked by defaut when the form is created.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the **data** parameters to specify some default choices, in your case specify an array, and use the **keys** of your available choices

```
$builder
    ->add('day', 'choice', [
        'choices' => $days,
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
        'label' => 'Jour(s) *',
        'data' => array_keys($days)
    ])
;
```

Comment: more information in doc: http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/form.html

Comment: Straightforward, powerful ! ;-)

Comment: Well, worth saying that it works only if you have a separate FormType for new and edit  actions, otherwise in edit form it will overwrites the DB values

Comment: If your choices are built up with `label => value` then you do `array_values` instead.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with a ChoiceType drop-down list, where I wanted to be able to set the selected value, but I couldn't figure out how to do that. I figured it out from @ThomasPiard 's answer. Thank you!

In my example, I set the 'choices', and the 'data' is set to the value of the array (not the key). This is important - since I couldn't figure out why it didn't work at first.

Here's my sample:

```
->add('pet_type', ChoiceType::class, array( // Select Pet Type.
        'choices' => array(
                'Substitution' => 'sub',
                'Equivalency' => 'equiv',
        ),
        'label' => 'Select Petition Type:',
        'attr' => array(
                'onchange' => 'changedPetType()',
        ),
        'placeholder' => 'Choose an option',
        'data' => 'equiv',
))
```

Hopefully it will help someone with the same problem.